# biber not working after updating XCode

Tags: errors, biber, macos

This is such a niche question and I've found an answer on the Apple SE site, but since I encountered the problem trying to use `biber` I'm asking it here and providing an answer in case other TeX users encounter the same problem while using TeX tools like `biber`.

After having updated XCode to the latest version (v14), `biber` now fails to run with a very strange set of errors:

$ biber bookauthor.bcf

```
2022-09-22 11:53:34.480 xcodebuild[32814:3443926] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0000): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'
2022-09-22 11:53:34.576 xcodebuild[32814:3443926] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21303/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/DataModel/DVTPlugIn.m:374
Details:  Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDESimulatorAvailability (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin)
Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running 'xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch'.

NSBundle error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability, 0x0109): Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimDiskImage)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDESimulatorAvailability'
  Expected in: '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator', NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESimulatorAvailability.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDESimulatorAvailability” couldn’t be loaded.}
Object:   <DVTPlugIn: 0x600001034e60>
Method:   -loadAssertingOnError:error:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x60000347c000>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010b759f81
  1  0x000000010b7594b5
  2  0x000000010b7596c1
  3  0x000000010b5d03ba
  4  0x000000010b58bc73
  5  0x000000010b589a1f
  6  0x00007ff815275317
  7  0x00007ff8152827ee
  8  0x000000010b7a85a1
  9  0x000000010b77e0d8
 10  0x000000010b5898a3
 11  0x000000010b589af5
 12  0x000000010c66ef66
 13  0x000000010c66e526
 14  0x000000010c66d919
 15  0x0000000109ff69a4
 16  0x0000000109d7920a
sh: line 1: 32820 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find lipo 2> /dev/null
lipo: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find lipo 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'lipo', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
biber: extracting x86_64 binary with lipo failed (wstatus=18432)
```

Then the following dialog shows up:

[image: install tools dialog]

This makes very little sense to me, since I *have* installed the Command Line Developer tools, and even when I click on the Install button, and rerun `biber` the behaviour repeats itself (same error, same dialog box).

I'm aware that this is likely a Mac problem not a `biber` problem per se, but asking here seems more likely to get an answer.

Comment: After messing about with this also, I managed to get it to work with: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the installation of XCode (including updating it through the App store is not in fact complete until you actually *open* the XCode app and choose to install at least the base frameworks. Until you do this, you will remain in the infinite installation loop described in the question.

Thanks to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/447992/how-to-fix-borked-xcode-commandline-tools for supplying the answer.